# Limit of this recursive sequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{4a_n+3}$$  $a_1=5$
I can solve simpler but I get stuck here because I cant find an upper bound or roots of the quadratic equation  $a_{n+1} -a_n= \frac{4a_n+3 - a_n^2}{\sqrt{4a_n +3}+a_n}...$ to find monotony.
I tried this generic aproach but have difficulties [Convergence and limit of a recursive sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685165/convergence-and-limit-of-a-recursive-sequence)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prove it using induction. Whether the sequence is increasing or decreasing depends on the value of $a_1$.  Observe that $$a_n \le a_{n+1} \implies 4a_n + 3 \le 4a_{n+1} + 3 \implies a_{n+1} \le a_{n+2}$$ and similarly $$a_n \ge a_{n+1} \implies 4a_n + 3 \ge 4a_{n+1} + 3 \implies a_{n+1} \ge a_{n+2}.$$ Thus if $a_1 \le a_2$ the full sequence is nondecreasing and if $a_1 \ge a_2$ the full sequence is nonincreasing.

Answer (score 5):

If you assume that the limit exists, then
$$ L=\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n $$
must satisfy:
$$ L^2 = 4L+3,\qquad L\geq 0, $$
hence the limit, if existing, is $2+\sqrt{7}$. Consider now that @Umberto P.'s answer gives that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonic.

Answer (score 4):

By the continuity of our recursive definition: if this sequence converges to a limit $a$, then that limit will be a solution to the equation
$$
a = \sqrt{4a + 3}
$$
So, solving for $a$, we have
$$
a^2 - 4a - 3 = 0 \implies\\
a = \frac{4 \pm\sqrt{4^2 +4\cdot 3}}{2} = 2 \pm \sqrt{7}
$$
Plugging into the original equation, we find that $2 - \sqrt{7}$ is an extraneous root, so that the only possibility would be $a = 2 + \sqrt{7}$.

It remains to be shown that the sequence does, in fact, converge to this limit (which the other answers have covered).

An idea to add to your attempts: try using the fact that $a_n$ will always be in an interval of the form $(a,a + \epsilon)$.

Comment: The fact that it converges to that limit how is it proved? Other answers proove the monotony only.is it enough ?

Comment: It's enough to show that, for all $n$, $a \leq a_{n+1} < a_n$.  We then have a monotonically decreasing sequence that is bounded from below.

Comment: my sequence with $a_0=5$ is increasing..

Comment: @Parhs [then you have done something wrong](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%29+%3D+sqrt%284+a%28n-1%29+%2B+3%29%2C+a%281%29+%3D+5).