# convergence of a recursively defined sequence with root alternative proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, recursion

I came across the following exercise and wanted to check whether my approach was wrong or correct.

(I have read the duplicated here [Convergence and limit of a recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{p+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685165/convergence-and-limit-of-a-recursive-sequence-x-n1-sqrtpx-n) but was wondering If I can also sort-of prove it with my method presented here:

Let $$ a_{n} = 1 , a_{n+1}= \sqrt[3]{a_{n}+6} $$ be a recursivley defined sequence that is supposedly bounded from above by 2. Now, when trying to prove it, can I use the fact that $$ \sqrt[3]{a_{n}+6} = (a_{n}+6)^{1/3} $$
and thus $$\sqrt[3]{a_{n+n}+6} = (a_{n}+6)^{1/3^{n}}$$ where the exponent of form 1/3 to the power of n will go to zero, thus the whole sequence converges to 1?

Of course, I will then continue the proof by using the definition of upper bound.

It just feels like I messed up some thought of concept or as though my prof will deduct points for this reasoning. Thanks for your efforts guys.

Comment: "*and thus*" $\;-\;$ That does not follow.

Comment: @dxiv what should then follow alternatively?

Comment: Try to go the way of the linked post.